# EOFError: Ran out of input : When command is typed

Tags: python, discord.py, eoferror

I am trying to create a .quote and .addquote command and have thme read off a file. When you type .addquote  it will put that quote in a file. Then when you type .quote it will send you a random quote that was sent into the file.

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands
from random import randint
import random
import asyncio
import pickle
import os
import json
from itertools import cycle
import time

Client = discord.Client()
status = ['Just', 'Being', 'Updated']
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.') #This will be the prefix for your bot
bot.remove_command("help")


@bot.event
async def on_message(message):

    if message.content.startswith('.quote'):
        with open("quote_file.pk1", "rb") as quote_file:
                quote_list = pickle.load(quote_file) #This is where i get the error 
        await bot.send_message(message.channel, random.choice(quote_list)) 

    if message.content.startswith('.addquote'):
        if not os.path.isfile("quote_file.pk1"):
            quote_list = []
        else:
            with open("quote_file.pk1", "rb") as quote_file:
                quote_list = pickle.load(quote_file)
        quote_list.append(message.content[9:])
        with open("quote_file.pk1", "wb") as quote_file:
            pickle.dump(quote_list, quote_file)
```

Heres the error im getting

```
      File "C:\Users\MYNAME\Desktop\MyBot\McVPS Bot.py", line 39, in on_message
    quote_list = pickle.load(quote_file)
EOFError: Ran out of input
```

I dont know where i am going wrong because this all looks correct in my opinion. I hope someone out there knows where im going wrong.

Comment: They line happens in two places. Which one causes the error?

Comment: Not sure why you tagged with TypeError

Comment: @MadPhysicist I editited it to show where it causes the error :D